# Почта попадает в спам

Tags: php, email, sendmail, phpmailer

Всем привет, у меня все сообщения попадают в спам и уже не знаю что мне делать. Я пишу на php и использую функцию mail. Вот тут [код](https://gist.github.com/Lisss13/d51622d0c68c1b724c4fb055cb9497f1)

```
$to = 'prob@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Заказ'; 
if($_POST['message'] == "" || $_POST['message'] == NULL) {
    $_POST['message'] = "Их нет";
}
$message = "
        <html>
            <head>
                <title> {$subject} </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>Имя: {$_POST['name']} </p>
                <p>Телефон: {$_POST['phone']} </p>
                <p>Товар: {$_POST['type']}</p>
                <p><strong>Пожелания:</strong><br/>{$_POST['message']}</p>
            </body>
        </html>"; 
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: <shop@vector.ru>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

[image: вот то, что приходит на почту]

на почту приходит вот это, и вроде все норм

Comment: Надо смотреть на исходник принятого письма, которое помечено как спам. Хотя так, навскидку, для начала я бы попробовал Subject закодировать в QP или base64.

Comment: Точно не помню как работает джимайл но попробуйте убрать адрес отправителя письма из обработчика. С майлом помогает.

Comment: @РусскийМедведь, каким образом абсолютно законный `From:` может влиять на спамдетектор? Вот отсутствие `To:` - может, но я не помню, подставляет ли его `mail()` из своих аргументов. В общем, на потроха письма смотреть надо. Может там дело вообще в каком-нибудь промежуточном сервере.

Comment: Вы бы открыли такое полученное письмо в сыром виде (в большинстве почтовых клиентов есть такая возможность, часто зовущаяся "Исходный текст"), т.е. текст со всеми заголовками и приложили его к вопросу. Тогда можно было бы его через какой нибуд spamassassin прогнать и посмотреть что ему не нравится в письме.

Answer (score 4):

Судя по коду вы отправляете от домена vector.ru
По DNS ваш SPF разрешает отправлять только с серверов yandex

> SPF records are published in DNS as TXT records.
>
> The TXT records found for your domain are: v=spf1
>   redirect=_spf.yandex.net

Нужно:

- либо настроить чтобы почта отправлялась через Yandex (smtp авторизацией)
  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

  ```
  $mail = new PHPMailer;

  //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

  $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
  $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
  $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
  $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
  ```
- либо проверьте что хост с которого идет отправка внесен в SPF список, и его sendmail формирует правильные заголовки.

Answer (score 4):

Долго боролся со SpamAssassin, и в итоге получился такой код, письмо проходит спам фильтр, с оценкой 3.9
Надеюсь поможет кому!

```
class mailTo {

    public function sendMail($email,$message,$subject)
    {
        $to  = $email;      
        $subject = '=?utf-8?b?'. base64_encode($subject) .'?=';
        $fromMail = 'admin@example.ru';
        $fromName = 'example.ru';
        $date = date(DATE_RFC2822);
        $messageId='<'.time().'-'.md5($fromMail.$to).'@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'>';
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8". "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ". $fromName ." <". $fromMail ."> \r\n";
        $headers .= "Date: ". $date ." \r\n";
        $headers .= "Message-ID: ". $messageId ." \r\n";

        return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    }
}
```